# const B and const A* are incompatible, even when B is aliased to A*

Tags: c++, constants, typedef

Why aren't `const B` and `const A*` indistinguishable, when `B` is typedef'ed to `A*`? When compiling this simple example:

```
struct A {};

typedef A* B;

void f1(const A* a1);
void f2(const B a2);

int main()
{
    const A a;
    f1(&a);
    f2(&a);
}
```

I get the following compiler output (G++ 6.3.1):

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:12:8: error: invalid conversion from ‘const A*’ to ‘B {aka A*}’ [-fpermissive]
     f2(&a);
```

Note that the call to `f1` is fine (since `&a` is-an `A*`), but `f2` is not, even though `const B` seems to me like it should be equivalent to `const A*`.

Comment: Wow, subtle. I had to read the code several times to remember what the issue is.

Comment: it's amazing how many dupes exist for this one.

Comment: @Walter when I asked it I was sure there were dupes out there, but I couldn't find the right set of keywords to use to find them; sorry about that!

Comment: @HaldeanBrown no need to be sorry. Happens all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const B` means `A * const` that is the pointer itself is a constant but the object pointed to by the pointer is not constant.

On the other hand `const A *` means that the pointer itself is not constant but the object pointed to by the pointer is constant.

So `const B` that is `A * const` is not an alias for `const A *`

You could write

```
typedef const A* B;

void f1(const A* a1);
void f2( B a2);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of "leading const" being misleading.

If you have

```
struct A {};

typedef A* B;
```

Then a `const B` is in fact `A * const`. The const-qualifier is applied on the *pointer-type*, not the *pointee-type* as it is in `const A*`.

---

Side note, but the reason I favor "cv-qualifiers on the right" is that reading the type name from right to left in English, matches the actual type defined. So for instance:

```
int const * * const * const p;
```

When read from right to left becomes "p is a constant pointer, to a constant pointer, to a pointer, to a constant integer".

Answer (score 2):

> even though `const B` seems to me like it should be equivalent to `const A*`.

No, for `const B`, `const` qualifies `B`, i.e. the pointer itself, not the pointee. Then `const B` is equivalent to `A* const`, i.e. a const pointer to non-const `A`, not a pointer to const `A`; which can't be converted from `const A*` without explicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

A `const A*` is a pointer to a `const A`.  The pointer is mutable, but the object it points to is not.
A `const B` is a `const` pointer to an `A`.  The pointer is immutable, but the object it points to is mutable.

The second function is equivalent to `void f2(A* const a2)`, if I recall.