# Weird behavior in function overload resolution with const keywords for template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading

So I have been reading `Programming Principles and Practices in C++` by Bjarne. And the section on conversion of templated objects of base/derived classes got me kinda confused. So I tried to try out different combinations and stumbled on something weird

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int i;
};

class B : public A {
    int j;
};

template<typename T>
class Array_ref{
public:

    Array_ref(T* pointer, int size) : p{pointer}, sz{size} {}
    template<typename Q>
    operator Array_ref<const Q>(){
        static_cast<Q>(*static_cast<T*>(nullptr));
        return Array_ref<const Q>{reinterpret_cast<Q*>(p), sz};
    }
    T& operator[](int n){ 
        return p[n];
    }
private:
    T* p;
    int sz;
};

void test_function(Array_ref<A* const> temp){
    if(temp[0]->i)
        std::cout<<"failed I guess"<<std::endl;
    exit(0);
};

int main(){
    B* testobj[1];
    testobj[0] = new B;
    testobj[0]->i = 0;
    Array_ref<B*> a(testobj, 1);
    test_function(a);
    delete testobj[0];
    exit(0);
}
```

The `void test_function(Array_ref<A* const> temp)` is the line that troubled me. Since if I made it `Array_ref<const A*>` it fails to compile with the error that it can't convert from `B*` to `const A*`, though as far as I know, I have provided the conversion rule which should fit the overloading arguments. In fact, aren't `const A*` and `A* const` very different things?

I would be glad if someone can help me out with where I am messing up, and what I missed out. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What's up with `static_cast<Q>(*static_cast<T*>(nullptr));`? Looks like unconditional UB.

Comment: temp[0]->i = 1; assigns to a const

Comment: @QuentinUK that's a desirable behavior, as i mentioned this is more of a program to clear my doubts relating to constant keyword, and it is just a leftover, I will edit and remove it so it does not confuses anyone

Comment: My main question was just on the `B*` to `const A*` conversion

Comment: With a pointer type, "Ptr", "const Ptr" means the pointer is const not the thing pointed at.

Comment: @QuentinUK But when template type will be resolved, won't it be just `const A*`, meaning, pointer to constant object A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `const A*` and `A* const` are very different things, and that's why your conversion operator `Array_ref<const Q>` cannot fulfill a parameter of type `Array_ref<const A*>`.

If `Q = A*`, then `const Q` = `Q const` = `A* const`.

Comment: `const Q` and `Q const` are completely equivalent. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190328/const-b-and-const-a-are-incompatible-even-when-b-is-aliased-to-a?noredirect=1&lq=1